# Application does not open after a few days of use

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

After building an app on Xcode for iphone 7 plus running iOS13, this particular app after a few days of use no longer opens. Simply executing it opens it, pops a white window and closes without any message. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: It's possible you have a memory leak and it's quitting because it's out of memory.  Completely quitting the app will likely allow it to run again.

Comment: Because the signed certificate is over. You need to install your app via XCode again.

Comment: Does not work again without reinstalling. Quitting the app by sliding it or turning off / restarting the phone does not work. The app will continue to open until you reinstall it.

Comment: Is there any definitive method so that you don't have to reinstall the app again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Free** development account has a 7 days running limit.

[image: Compare]
As you can see, you need to pay for developer program to continue using your app in your device or as the comment suggests, you can rebuild again and again using Xcode and get another 7 free days, but you'll lose all the data of your app. Also there is a limit for how many apps you can build with your free development account in this period and also a limit for how many devices can carry this kind of app.

Image Source: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/